# Why does Mathematica remove some formatting?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, save, pdf-format

I'm trying to save a file as PDF. Using `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout"]` so it looks nice. There are a bunch of formulas, and every time I save it, it flattens one of them. Not the same one every time, but I fix one, it flattens another, or the same one, or both, or three, in no particular order...
So, for example, [image]
gets saved as
[image]

How do I make it keep formatting? Also, how do I make it save in color? I used "Working" printout before but it messed up margins and text size and was just all bad...

here's the code if you want to try it:
`d\[Sigma] = Limit[4 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) ((Subscript[\[Mu]V, 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\))/\[HBar]^2)^2 (Sin[
       Subscript[qr, 0]] - 
      Subscript[qr, 0] Cos[Subscript[qr, 0]])^2/(Subscript[qr, 0])^6, 
   Subscript[qr, 0] -> 0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really an answer, but if you select this expression and go to Menu/Evaluation/EvaluateInPlace you will repair your formula. May be this helps.

You might also want to define a simple function to apply it to each your expression to prevent any its unwanted reformatting. like this, for example:

```
rE[expr_] := 
  Rasterize[Evaluate[expr] // TraditionalForm, RasterSize -> 400];
```

Then you can apply it to you expressions as follows:

```
 d\[Sigma] == Limit[4 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) ((Subscript[\[Mu]V, 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\))/\[HBar]^2)^2 (Sin[
         Subscript[qr, 0]] - 
        Subscript[qr, 0] Cos[Subscript[qr, 0]])^2/(Subscript[qr, 
        0])^6, Subscript[qr, 0] -> 0] // rE
```

I just attract your attention that to obtain a nicely looking expression you need to use "==" instead of "=", when interpreted by the TraditionalForm function. Further, the function returns an image, rather than the Mma formula. But that image will not be reformatted in any way. That is what you will obtain:

[image]

If you need more contrast, play with the RasterSize, If you need the Mma expression in the form of a formula, skip the Rasterize part.

Have fun!

Comment: interesting :] I guess that'll work, thanks!